# Como intercambiar un valor en un arreglo

Tags: c

Tengo un arreglo de caracteres, ejemplo:

`char a [] = "abcdef"`

El usuario carga la letra "c" y necesito insertarla sin alterar el orden alfabético, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Es tan sencillo como insertar una letra en un arreglo sin alterar el orden indicado.

Comment: No entiendo como insertar la letra y cambiar las posiciones de los otros elementos

Comment: Mueves los elementos e insertas.

Comment: ¿Y no tienes nada de código con el que hayas intentado algo? ¿aunque no haya salido?

Comment: Solo pude hacer una funcion que recorra el arreglo y nos devuelva la posicion del elemento si es que el mismo esta

Comment: @JulianGimenez Agrega ese código en la pregunta, si no te salió, no importa, eso denota tu esfuerzo :)